# How to deploy to target site with custom web part

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I am developing a custom web part for a project that I am working on.
I am new to sharepoint development, and trying to get an idea of how all this fits together.

I have a dev server, and two sites which are already created in it. Like this:

- http://localhost/
- http://localhost/SiteOne

After I created the web part and selected deploy, I found that you can only find the Custom web part in the main site, e.g.

- http://localhost/

If I go into SiteOne, the web part does not appear in the Custom folder.

If I go to the main localhost root, it does.

Also, in SiteOne, in enable site collection features, the control is no where to be seen.

How do I target deploy to a specific app, in this case, SiteOne? Is this just by manually editing the Site URL from http://computername/ to http://computername/SiteOne ?

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, Visual Studio gives you a nice shortcut to deploy the webpart to a specific location. 
Read up on [deploying SharePoint solutions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262995.aspx) for a broader view on what is going on and the steps visual studio is hiding inside the "Deploy" button.